# Double stochastic integrals - relationship

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Suppose that $W$ is the standard Brownian motion and $f$ is a smooth function. Why is

\begin{equation}
\int_u \int_s f(u) dW_u f(v) dW_v = \left(\int_u f(u) dW_u  \right)^2 - \int_u f^2(u) du
\end{equation}

Any pointers or name of this relationship?

Comment: The standard definition of multiple (e.g. double) stochastic integrals excludes diagonals from integration. In a sense, $\int f(u)^2 du$ stands for the integral along the diagonal: 
$$\int_{u = v} f(u,v) dW_u dW_v \approx \lim \sum f(t_k)^2 (\Delta W_{t_k})^2 \approx \lim \sum f(t_k)^2 \Delta {t_k} \approx \int f(u)^2 du.$$
More generally, you can write that
$$
\iint f(u) g(v) dW_u dW_v = \int f(u) dW_u  \int g(v) dW_v - \int f(u) du  \int g(v) dv.
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set $X_t := \int_0^t f(u) \, dW_u$, then by Itô's formula (with $f(x)=x^2$)

\begin{align*} X_t^2 &= 2 \int_0^t X_s \, dX_s + \frac{2}{2} \int_0^t \langle X \rangle_s \\ &= 2\int_0^t X_s f(s) \, dW_s + \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds \\ &= \int_0^t \left( \int_0^t f(r) \, dW_r \right) f(s) \, dW_s + \int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds. \end{align*} (See @Zhoraster's comment below for the second "=".) Rearranging the terms, proves the assertion.

Comment: Just a quick question, where does the "2" in the first term of $2\int_0^t X_s dX_s$ disappear to?

Comment: @Crushh, this is because the integral here is only a half of the "complete" integral: $$\int_0^t X_s dX_s = \int_0^t \int_0^s f(u) f(s) dW_u dW_s\\ = \iint_{0\le u<s\le t} f(u) f(s) dW_u dW_s\\ = \frac12 \int_0^t \int_0^t f(u) f(s) dW_u dW_s.$$

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks! I got it !!